# Error: could not find libjava.so Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment. while running elasticsearch 6.5.4 on docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am facing this issue while I migrated from Apple Intel chip to Apple M1 chip. I am using the latest version of the docker desktop 3.6.0 and macbook pro 13" (2020 model).

Unfortunately I can't upgrade the elasticsearch version from 6.5.4.

Any work arounds people came up with?

this is the docker-compose.yml file

```
elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.4
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
```

this is the error am getting

```
Error: could not find libjava.so  
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

Answer (score 2):

The following configuration worked perfectly on Apple Macbook pro 13" (2020) - M1 chip

```
elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0-arm64
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
```

Answer (score 0):

ARM version of elastic in docker is only available since 7.8.0 according to this article [Running Elasticsearch on ARM](https://www.elastic.co/fr/blog/elasticsearch-on-arm)

Comment: thanks ExploZe, though it says 7.8.0 works on ARM architecture it gives error on Apple silicon chip... IndexFormatTooNewException[Format version is not supported (resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(SimpleFSIndexInput(path="/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/segments_3"))): 10 (needs to be between 7 and 9)];

Comment: It seems you tried to start on data which are incompatible with this version, `This exception is thrown when Lucene detects an index that is newer than this Lucene version.` https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexFormatTooNewException.html